# How can i redirect to my ownpage before the 404.php page redirection?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have a page in my site which is not created in my WP-admin pages,posts or category. when in entered the page name in url it redirects to 404.php page. Now my question is how can i execute that page without rediects to 404.php page?.

I need to control the redirection before the 404.php redirection happens?.
Is that possible?.please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe url rewriting allows all url's to redirect to one script and with that you can then redirect the user to the file they requested, and if the file the user requested does not exist, you can create your own page for 404.

Comment: i have 404.php page.but i don't want to redirect to that page.before it happens i need to redirect.now i executed the pages  from 404 page. but in browser it shows 404 not found (in inspect element)

Comment: What I meant was, when you run url rewriting all urls to your domain (e.g. www.example.com) will firstly go to an "index" file as example, and from that file you determine if that is a valid location or not. If it is valid redirect them to that page, and if it is invalid redirect to 404.php .